# PHP: Mysql ("SELECT WHERE ID NOT ")

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to exclude the an 'ID' from the Mysql_query but it is still returning the mentioned ID.
This ID is '21' but the query returns '21' which is not what I wanted.
Did I misspell something in the Mysql?

```
("SELECT * FROM `gallery` WHERE `gallery_id` NOT IN ('$notgallery')") or die (mysql_error());
```

```
function not_gallery($pic){

$pic = $_GET['id'];
$id = explode(".", $pic);
$notgallery = $id;

$notg = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `gallery` WHERE `gallery_id` NOT IN ('$notgallery')") or die (mysql_error());
while($not_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($notg)){
    $notgimage[] = array(
        'id' => $not_row['gallery_id'],
        'user' => $not_row['user_id'],
        'name' => $not_row['name'],
        'timestamp' => $not_row['timestamp'],
        'ext' => $not_row['ext'],
        'caption' => $not_row['caption'],

    );
}
print_r($notgimage);
}
```

I print_r'ed the query and it is still returning '21' which I have excluded/or which I thought I did

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 21 [user] => 18 [name] => NotDeojeff [timestamp] => 1367219713 [ext] => jpg [caption] => asd ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 22 [user] => 18 [name] => NotDeojeff [timestamp] => 1367225648 [ext] => jpg [caption] => Ogre magi )
```

Comment: Can you print_r `$_GET['id']` and `$notgallery`?

Comment: try echoing the query (not the result). What's it's content?

Comment: Array ( [0] => 21 [1] => jpg ) 21.jpg

Comment: You're passing in the results of `explode`, which gives you an array. You'll need to `implode` it again, using a comma as the glue.

Comment: WHERE gallery_id != $notgallery

Comment: `$notgallery` is an array.  I assume the `.jpg` extension is not needed, so I think you mean `"WHERE gallery_id != {$notgallery[0]}"`.

Comment: Also, you're quoting the string you're passing in to IN; that will mean that you'll only match the entire string, rather than individual values. `IN ('12,21')` is different to `IN(12,21)`

Comment: When some SQL query doesn't do what you want, always print out the query and check if everything is ok.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a couple of problems. Take a look here:

```
"SELECT * FROM `gallery` WHERE `gallery_id` NOT IN ('$notgallery')"
```

`$notgallery` is currently an array of IDs to check. You need to join them back together with `implode`, like this:

```
$notgallery = implode(', ', $id);
```

Also, you have wrapped `gallery_id`'s NOT IN value in quotes. So in fact you'd get something like:

```
"SELECT * FROM `gallery` WHERE `gallery_id` NOT IN ('21, 13')"
```

Which is like saying `WHERE gallery_id != '21, 13'`. Presuming you're using `INT`s for the `id` column, you need to remove the single quotes around `$notgallery`. If you are using a string, you can alter your implode:

```
$notgallery = implode("', '", $id);
```

Answer (score 4):

$notgallery is an array and in your SQL query you must have a list of id separated by a comma, so try:

```
$pic = $_GET['id'];
$id = explode(".", $pic);
$notgallery = $id;
$notgallery = implode(",", $notgallery);
$notg = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `gallery` WHERE `gallery_id` NOT IN ($notgallery)") or die (mysql_error());
```

Comment: Wouldn't `$notgallery = str_replace('.', ',', $pic);` make way more sense?

Answer (score 2):

has above post n better way to put it.

```
$pic = $_GET['id'];
$id = explode(".", $pic);
$notgallery = $id;
$notgallery = implode(",", $notgallery);
$notg = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `gallery` WHERE `gallery_id` NOT IN ($notgallery)") or die (mysql_error());
```